# My code claims to have an unexpected token

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>lorem ipsum</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body{
                background-color:#222222;
                margin:0px;
                padding:0px;
            }
            #typed{
                color:red;
                font-size:150%;
                float:left;
            }
            .cursor{
                height:24px;
                width:2px;
                background:lawngreen;
                float:left;
                opacity:0;
                animation:blink 0.75s linear infinite alternate;

            }
            @keyframes blink{
                50% {
                    opacity:0;
                }
                100% {
                    opacity:1;
                }
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="typed"></div>
        <div class="cursor"></div>

    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var i;
        var txt='lorem ipsum';
        var speed=50;

       for (i=0; i<txt.length;i++){ 
           setInterval(addLetter("typed"),speed);
       }


        function addLetter(word){
            document.getElementById(word).innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
            i++;
        }
</script>
</html>
```

I cannot see why it thinks it's wrong, but perhaps I'm just missing something. Chrome tells me that the error is an uncaught syntax error in the for loop, the error, it says, is the ")". I've been trying to figure it out all day long.

EDIT: What I'm trying to do is get the text in the variable, "txt" to pop up on screen as if being typed out. I fixed it with the below suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `,` by `;` in for loop.
`for (i=0; i<txt.length;i++){` 
Also, remove the `}` before  `</script>`.

Comment: This worked in getting the code to show the text. It did not work in doing what I wanted overall though, which I suppose I should have been more clear on that. I edited my post so that you can see what changes I made and what my hopes are for it to do.

Comment: You can't just change the question like that, the original question has been answered by this, if you have another problem, create another question.

Comment: didn't know. First time user, sorry. I will mark it as answered and ask again. Thank you,